# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: password authentication failed for user " " after npm start

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript

I am using node version 8 and when i do an npm start below errors are seen. I guess after routes are created below errors are seen. Here "techwedge3" is the username of my system. The application works correctly even with the below errors.
Even i am able to connect to my postgres db.
Any idea on how to resolve the issue?

```
[JobRoute::create] Creating route.
[InterviewRoute::create] Creating route.
[Creating AdminRoute::create] Creating route.
[TenantRoute::create] Creating route.
[CriteriaRoute::create] Creating route.
(node:12212) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: password authentication failed for user "techwedge3"
    at Connection.parseE (C:\Development\vilearnnew\vilearn_node\node_modules\pg-promise\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:546:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Development\vilearnnew\vilearn_node\node_modules\pg-promise\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:371:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Development\vilearnnew\vilearn_node\node_modules\pg-promise\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:114:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Where do you store the password? Is it `process.env`? Also, please, show us the code that initiates the connection (ideally, omitting any sensitive information).